# AutoCompleteExtender OnClientItemSelected raised after validation

Tags: asp.net, ajax, validation, toolkit, extender

I have an AutoCompleteExtender which is working, the OnClientItemSelected event is raised. Now, I added a validator that validates my control (the AutoCompleteExtender is a part of that control). My problem is that the validator is called before the OnClientItemSelected event is raised. Therefore the validator returns an invalid state, which is not correct if a valid value has been entered.

Does anybody know this behavior and can come up with a solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue with a little workaround some days ago: The validator is disabled per default and will be enabled before the user presses the save button. After that the validator is disabled again. It's not the niciest way, but it works.